# Spring-MVC : Redirect to html page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Here is the code structure

[image]

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class indexController {

@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(){
    return "index";
}
}
```

web.xml

[image]

although my views folder contains index.html
but still when i run the project on server, browser shows 404 error.

please help

** because of tag i am not able to post the code of web.xml hence its a screenshot

Comment: can you try  removing request mapping on top of the controller name and see if it works ?

Comment: thanks , i tried but it is not working :(

Comment: in my spring mvc project, i had jsp views. could you try renaming your index.html to index.jsp ?

Comment: yeah for jsp it is working , but why not for html ?

Comment: @sparsh610 .jsp extension helps server recognize that the request has been sent by a JSP page, converts it into servlet content and compiles the servlet into an executable class. If the extension is HTML server does not recognize it as JSP and hence no class is created at the server

Answer (score 0):

web container treat .html format as static file , they don't render them but .jsp is their know extension , and they try to render that.  So, If you put html files under, lets say static folder static/views/html/yourHtml.html and put something like this in configuration

```
     mvc:resources mapping="/html/**" location="/static/views/html/"
```

It should work then.
This way they will be treated as resources files and they can be served.
 Hope it helps.